# Is possible to store repository issues in the git repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is possible to store the project issues in its git repository?

I know that git doesn't support this feature and the issues are stored in the provider site (eg. Bitbucket, Github).

---

I would like to develop a project as a free private repository on Bitbucket, and when it is finished to make it open source moving it to Github. The problem is that the issues reported in the Bitbucket repo will not be available in the Github repo, because they are stored in the Bitbucket databases.

---

Which is the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues are kind of orthogonal to code (i.e. they transcend version snapshots), so it's useful to have a separate system for them. As such, git has no built-in system for issue tracking.

Since BitBucket and GitHub both have APIs for issues, there are easy ways to migrate the issues across. Searching for "migrate bitbucket issues to github" produces [at least one](https://github.com/vbabiy/bitbucket_issue_migration) script to do exactly that.

Comment: "Issues are kind of orthogonal to code" I'm not sure I agree with this. Surely different versions of your code have different issues.

Comment: What is gained by storing issue information using the same machinery we use for source code? Cryptographic hashing? Viewing history in the commit log? How are those useful? Portability we can get from API access. Now ask yourself what is lost, and you'll come up with the best argument to use a separate system: **if you store your issues in Git, non-developers cannot interact with them.** That's a pretty big loss for most projects.

Comment: Well you could build a website that leverages the git issues in the repo and shares that with a non-technical end user. This way people aren't dependent on one single host (github) for development,  also you could create github actions to add issues/comments from the repo. You could also store mailing list discussions in the repo if you want to be "offline friendly"

Answer (score 11):

You can use [git-bug](https://github.com/MichaelMure/git-bug) or [git-issue](https://github.com/dspinellis/git-issue). Both of these projects implement an issue tracker that stores issues directly into your git repository. That way you can migrate your repo between any git service.